# select fields from table based on selected field of other table in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

to make things short, i am writing a web app which implements users and groups. multiple users have multiple groups. that leaves me with three tables: user, group, usergroup.

now i have a webform in which i want to manage groups and their members. for this, i have two gridviews on said form. one is for displaying the groups, another for displaying the members of the selected group.

the group-gridview hast two columns: description and another where a buttonfield resides which says "display members". when the user clicks this button, he will get a list of users based on the selected group in the other gridview.

however, i dont really have a clue how to do this? can you please point me in the right direction here?

here is my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<h1>Gruppenverwaltung</h1>    
<asp:Panel ID="pnlGruppe" ScrollBars="Both" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnNeueGruppe" Text="Neue Gruppe" runat="server" OnClick="btnNeueGruppe_Click" />
    <asp:GridView DataKeyNames="GruppenID" OnRowCommand="grdGruppe_RowCommand" ID="grdGruppe" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Bezeichnung" HeaderText="Bezeichnung" SortExpression="Bezeichnung" />
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="MitgliederAnzeigen" Text="Mitglieder anzeigen" />
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Archivieren" ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Bezeichnung], [GruppenID] FROM [Gruppe] WHERE [Archiviert] != 1"
        DeleteCommand="UPDATE Gruppe SET [Archiviert] = 1 WHERE [GruppenID] = @GruppenID"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Button ID="btnZurueck" Text="Zurück" runat="server" OnClick="btnZurueck_Click" />
</asp:Panel>  
<asp:Panel Visible="false"  ID="pnlMitglieder" ScrollBars="Both" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="grdBenutzer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Zurück" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["UserAuthentication"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
    }

    protected void btnZurueck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Datenverwaltung.aspx");
    }

    protected void btnNeueGruppe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("NeueGruppe.aspx");
    }

    protected void grdGruppe_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "MitgliederAnzeigen")
        {
            pnlMitglieder.Visible = true;
            pnlGruppe.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pnlMitglieder.Visible = false;
        pnlGruppe.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: nobody got any answer? i just need the sql statement that lets me select the first and last name from the user table. but as it goes through one "middle" table due to many to many relationship, i dont know how this works...

Answer (score 1):

protected void grdGruppe_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

```
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "MitgliederAnzeigen")
        {
        string rowindex = e.CommandArgument as string;//Get Row Index
         string  str = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(rowindex)].Cells[0].Text;

           pnlMitglieder.Visible = true;
            pnlGruppe.Visible = false;
        }
```

After Geting GroupName in str  u can bind ur second grid view according to that hope it will help u

Comment: thanks for the answer. however, i selected the groupid since it is actually possible for two groups to have the same name. now i just need to get the userid's from the usergroup table and display the first and last name according the the userid from the user table...i have updated my code above

Comment: sorry leonidas i couldnt understand what u asking in comment..i think u need group id instead of name right
for that define the datakeys field of ur gridview with ur groupid.....and u can get this id by gridview1.datakey[rowindex].tostring();
hope that what u need!!!!

Comment: when i click on the "Mitglieder anzeigen" button i need to get all userid from the usergroup table that have a reference field to the group id. then, based on those userid's, i need to get the first and last names from the user table. i already have the groupid, now i just need to somehow get the user data from the user table to display...

Comment: HOW MANY TABLE U HAVE  WHAT ARE THERE COLUMNS......

SELECT FIRST_NANME , LAST_NAME FROM USER_TABLE WHERE USER_ID IN (sELECT * FROM REFRENCE GROUPTABLE WHERE GROUP ID=STR)